# After Laravel internal API call controller redirects to localhost

Tags: laravel-5.7, php-7.2, dingo-api

I am using Laravel internal API calls, After internal call is complete i want to redirect to list page via same controller function. when i use redirect methods to redirect it redirects to http://localhost/
localhost should be IP address of website, 
I am running web-server on IP address

**server run:**

```
sudo php artisan serve --host=ip-address --port=8001
```

**Laravel internal API call:**

```
$roleApiRequest = Request::create($url,$method,$reqData);
$response = app()->handle($roleApiRequest);
$data = json_decode($response->getContent(),true);
$resStatus = $response->status();
```

This response contains data and after taking data i redirect to index page of module.

```
Redirect::route('roles.list');
```

**It redirects to URL : http://localhost/roles (gives URL not found because actual URL is http://ip-address/roles)**

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput($input);
```

Redirect back works properly for previous urls but the back URL is not desired URL to redirect.

I think when call is made for internal API, Laravel replaces base URL with localhost for internal call and when we call redirect method it points to localhost.

I am using Dingo API for web-services.

Please help.

Comment: have you added the IP address to the .env file? APP_URL=

Comment: @Dave I tried it but still it is redirecting me to localhost url. I also ran php artisan config:cache command to clear the cache after making changes to the .env file